# Альтернативные варианты подключения библиотеки librosa

Tags: python, anaconda, librosa

У меня есть установленный пакет с Librosa.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, когда я импортирую его, появляется следующая ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'
```

Варианты переустановки:

```
pip install librosa
sudo pip install librosa
pip install -u librosa
```

Или в среде conda:

Сначала `conda install -c numba numba`

Затем `conda install -c conda-forge librosa`

Проблему не решили

Comment: Не из того окружения значит запускаете, в которое ставите. Разберитесь сколько у вас питонов на машине, какие у вас окружения питона есть.

Comment: @CrazyElf да разобрался вроде. Спасибо за наводку!